# Button not clickable over iframe on mobile web

Tags: reactjs, iframe, mobile, mobile-safari, stoppropagation

I am attempting to place a button absolutely *over* an iframe. When viewing my app in mobile web, however, no button click is registered; iInstead, a click is registered on the iframe that's *underneath* it.

The exact same implementation works on non-mobile web.

[image: Here is a picture of the implementation for visualization purposes]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```html
<div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh', display: 'flex', position: 'relative' }} />
   <button
      style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, zIndex: 1  }}
      onClick={() => console.log('button clicked')}
   >
      click here
   </button>

   <iframe style={{ width: '100%' }} src={src} />
</div>
```

A few other things I have tried:

- Setting the `z-index` of the `iframe` to a lower number (`iframe` still gets clicked)
- Disabling `pointer-events` on the `iframe` (the button click is still not registered)
- Wrapping the `button` in a `div`
- Wrapping the `iframe` in a `div`
- Stopping propagation of the click event of the `button`

Comment: Have you tried anything else so far?

Comment: just what I have in the question

Comment: @AbdullahAlhariri: That's a strange thing to ask when the original post literally includes a bullet list of all of the things that they have tried.